# OrmLite java.lang.IllegalStateException: you must call initialize() before you can use the dao

Tags: android, dao, ormlite

I am using ORMLite to persist my object in my `SqliteDatabase` in my app.

I am getting this exception while trying to get a DAO in order to persist an object.

The documentation says I have to call the `initialize()` method before I can use the DAO, and the OrmLite documentation (insufficient) says:

> **BaseDaoImpl (class)**
>   initialize(): Initialize the various DAO configurations after the various setters have been called.

The problem is, I get the DAOs by calling `getDao(class)`, and there is no `initialize()` that I can call neither on DAOs nor in my class that extends `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`.

This is my custom `OpenHelper` class code:

```
public class LocalDBHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
  private LocalDBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  public static LocalDBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) instance = new LocalDBHelper(context);
    return instance;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Barrio.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Fenomeno.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Info.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, TelefonoUtil.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Alarma.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, ReplicaAlerta.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try {
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Barrio.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Fenomeno.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Info.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, TelefonoUtil.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Alarma.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, ReplicaAlerta.class, true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

And this is the full stack of Android Monitor:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: you must call initialize() before you can use the dao
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.checkForInitialized(BaseDaoImpl.java:1061)
        at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:316)
        at com.org.siam.app.controller.BarrioController.actualizarTodos(BarrioController.java:75)
        at com.org.siam.app.remote.BarriosWebService.onResponse(BarriosWebService.java:43)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

EDIT: added an `Application` subclass called `SiacApplication`, `onCreate()` method code here (also registered on manifest):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LocalDBHelper.getInstance(this);
}
```

EDIT 2: added DAO getter (the DAO is a local field):

```
    public Dao<Barrio, Long> getBarrioDao() throws SQLException {
    if (barrioDao == null) barrioDao = getDao(Barrio.class);
    return barrioDao;
}
```

Comment: I think your applicationContext is always null, thus it thinks it's not initalized.

Comment: I have editted with my changes. Still getting same exception.

Comment: Something is wrong with your DAO instance.  You sure you got it from the helper?   Can you please show the actual code that builds the dao?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same problem in Android. It seems that it's required to send ConnectionSource while creating DAO.

In my case only creating wrapper classes for DAO helped because there is no getDao() method variation with such parameter.

So i created wrapper

```
class BarrioDao {
  public BarrioDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource) throws SQLException{
        super(connectionSource, Barrio.class); 
 }
}
```

getter for dao in LocalDBHelper looked like:

```
public BarrioDao getBarrioDao() throws SQLException {
    if (barrioDao == null) barrioDao = new BarrioDao(getConnectionSource());
    return barrioDao;
}
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the ORMLite documentation which uses: DaoManager.createDao(connection, Contact.class); This command will automatically use custom DAO classes (extending BaseDaoImpl) if you specify the custom DAO class in the entity class annotation: @DatabaseTable(daoClass=MyCustomDao.class).
I ended up here because I encountered this error when I accidentally new'ed up a service class that depended on my custom DAO--instead of injecting it.

Answer (score 0):

for everyone got this error,

***WHY I GET THIS ERROR:***

When beginning creating your DAO any **runtime exception** does **interrupt** your **DAO initialization** and it makes you got this error.

***HOW TO SOLVE IT :***

1 - Check every throw ORMlite and SQLite exception from your DaoHelper class.

2 - Try to correct every error you got and stop every exception that can be thrown.

3 - Run your application without any runtime exception when beginning creating your DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same problem and realized that it was caused by changing the name of one of my database fields and running the code without regenerating the `ormlite_config.txt`.

When the ORMLite system was trying to load my class config and initialize the DAOs, it saw the config in `ormlite_config.txt` said there was a fieldname called `oldname` and then looked at the java class definition and didn't see an instance variable for `oldname` so it threw an exception which corrupted the rest of the process.

So, if you run into this error, make sure you regenerate your `ormlite_config.txt` file and try running again.